# How do I sum by certain conditions and into a new data frame?

Tags: pandas, group-by, sum

[dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vNvxy.png)

[my attempted solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/54pQN.png)

I'm trying to make a bar chart that shows the percentage of non-white employees at each company. In my attempted solution I've summed the counts of employee by ethnicity already but I'm having trouble taking it to the next step of summing the employees by all ethnicities except white and then having a new df with columns of company and % of non-white employees.

How should I go about it? Is my method of using groupby first incorrect?

I've tried using

e2 = df_ethnicities.groupby(["Company", "Ethnicity"]).agg({"Count": sum}).reset_index()

to first get the counts of each ethnicity by company.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can drop the `reset_index`and then `unstack`. This will result in a Dataframe has the different counts for the different etnicities as columns. 1 minus the % of white employees will then yield the desired formula.

```
df_agg = df_ethnicities.groupby(["Company", "Ethnicity"]).agg({"Count": sum}).unstack()
percentatges = 1-df_agg[('Count','White')]/df_agg.sum(axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

The group by to get the count is a good approach, now to get percentage, I would do the following:

Sum the counts of each ethnicity by company

```
ethnicity_counts = df_ethnicities.groupby(["Company", "Ethnicity"])["Count"].sum()
```

Sum the counts of non-white employees by company

```
nonwhite_counts = ethnicity_counts.loc[pd.IndexSlice[:, ~'White'], :].groupby("Company").sum()
```

Calculate the total counts of employees by company

```
total_counts = ethnicity_counts.groupby("Company").sum()
```

Calculate the percentage of non-white employees for each company

```
percent_nonwhite = nonwhite_counts / total_counts * 100
```

Create a new dataframe with the company and percent non-white columns

```
df_percent_nonwhite = percent_nonwhite.reset_index(name="% Non-White")
```